# No description filter on tags page

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-wiki

Having a filter for no description would be helpful because then the tag editors can quickly tell which tags they need to make descriptions for.

Comment: would be happy to add this, but I need a name for this new tab, also ... if we allow voting on wikis we could pick up all problem wikis there as well (wikis with -1 score or less)

Comment: Yes, I agree, we need a name. For example, descriptionless... no description... needs description... etc. Maybe we would like to have some suggestions and a vote? Which ever one gets upvoted the most? Just a thought.

Comment: The bounty ends in 14 hours. I am looking for someone to commit to taking action for this and I will award the bounty to them as a token of my gratitude.

Comment: I think "No Description" would work as a name unless someone can come up with a better one.

Comment: @waffles Sience you have shown the most interest, could you please make your comment into an answer so I can award the bounty to you? Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, that would be handy.

However, it might be useful if we applied a noise filter to it, to somewhat vet the tags first.  Something like: *Must have 5 questions using the tag before it appears in this list.*

Comment: Yes, maybe we could make a sub-tabset that controlled how many questions tagged with said tag to make it appear in the list...

Comment: Yes, it would be handy. Could you or someone else please talk to whoever needs to be talked to to get this implememted?